# Anotação @Scheduled Spring verificar ambiente

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Tenho um controller anotado com `@Scheduled` porém quando o ambiente de teste está ativo ele também é executado.

É possível verificar o ambiente em que aplicação está rodando para que o método seja executado apenas em produção?

Comment: Este ambiente de teste sobe usando um outro arquivo de propriedades do Spring? O seu código precisa saber, de alguma forma, que está em um ambiente diferente (no caso, de teste) para conseguir controlar isto.

Comment: @Dherik é o mesmo arquivo. Existe alguma forma de separa-los?

Comment: Acredito que [isto aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40227145/4319922) ajude você, especificamente a segunda parte da resposta dele, quando ele usa `@ConditionalOnProperty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso exista alguma tabela de parâmetros para o sistema, você poderia adicionar a informação do ambiente e verificar se é de produção para poder executar o método.
Dependendo do seu cenário essa seria uma solução mais simples.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma variável em um arquivo de properties próprio para teste, para ter suas propriedades de teste separadas das "default" (do arquivo `application.properties`)

Primeiro, vamos criar o arquivo no seguinte formato, para criar um perfil (*profile*) de teste (`tst`):

```
application-tst.properties
```

Incluia neste arquivo de properties uma configuração para você entender qual o ambiente em que está:

```
ambiente = teste
```

E no arquivo original `application.properties`, adicionar:

```
ambiente = producao
```

Assim distinguimos os dois ambientes. Agora você pode executar sua aplicação [usando este novo perfil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40061235/2387977) (`tst`).

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=tst
```

Ou:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=tst XXX.jar
```

Depois usar a anotação `@ConditionalOnProperty`:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="ambiente", havingValue="producao")
public class Schedule {
    @Scheduled
    public class algumScheduler() {
        // código
    }
}
```

Se preferir, pode usar o `@ConditionalOnProperty` no próprio método também, se desejar.

Comment: Obrigada por me ajudar, e esse cenário funcionaria sim porém com a tabela de parâmetros para o sistema (como a sugestão acima) tive mais facilidade para resolver a questão.

Comment: @JoyceSD, legal, soluções simples são quase sempre as melhores.